# Finding the expectation of a random variable that is a function of another random variable

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Suppose we have two variables $x,y$ , where

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 3x, $ where $0\leq y \leq x \leq1$ and

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ elsewhere

I am having trouble finding $E(Y)$.

$E(Y) = \int_{0}^{1}y*f_Y(y)dy$

$ = \int_{0}^{1}y* (\int_0^xf_{X,Y}(x,y) dx)dy$

$=\int_{0}^{1}y*(\int_0^x3xdx)dy$

$= \int_{0}^{1}y*\frac{3x^3}{2}dy$

Which will not lead to a constant. Expectation of Y cannot be in terms of X, so this is a wrong approach. What is my mistake?

Here is a screenshot of the problem stem (Wackerly's Mathematical Statistics):
[image: xto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that the given function is not a valid joint pdf, since it integrates to $1/2$, not to $1$:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^y 3x\,dx\,dy = \frac12.
$$
So I supposed that it should be $6x$ instead of $3x$.

Next, $f_Y(y)$ depends on $y$, not on $x$. In order to find it, you should integrate joint pdf over all possible range of $x$. For any $y\in(0,1)$, $x$ belongs to $[0,y]$, so
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_0^y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx.
$$

Comment: There's my mistake! Thanks also for pointing out that this is not a valid pdf (although I don't think I made a mistake citing the problem, see screenshot I added above)

Comment: Thank you! The option $f(x,y)=3y$, $0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$ did not occur to me.